# How to get the out value from store procedure without property mapping in mybatis3 annotaion

Tags: mybatis

I am calling the store procedure using select annotation and I have one OUT param. But I am not setting that property. Is it possible to retrieve the OUT param without property mapping in mybatis3 annotation

Comment: try to set parameterType to map, then use some value instead of `?` placeholder, perhaps it will populate parametre map with that value.

Answer (score 0):

For call stored procedures with Out params try this:

**Mapper:**

```
@Select("{ CALL SABIUS.GI_ACESSO_PORTAL.VALIDA_CARTEIRA_USUARIO("
+ "#{map.param1, mode=IN, jdbcType=INTEGER },"
+ "#{map.param2, mode=IN, jdbcType=INTEGER },"
+ "#{map.param3, mode=IN, jdbcType=INTEGER },"
+ "#{map.paramOUT, mode=OUT, jdbcType=INTEGER }" + ") }")
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
public void methodCall(@Param("map") Map<String, Object> mapParameters);
```

**in DAO**

```
Map<String, Object> mapParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
mapParameters.put("param1", 123);
mapParameters.put("param2", 234);
mapParameters.put("param3", 345);

mapper.methodCall(mapParameters);
return mapParameters.get("paramOUT");
```

the hashmap is updated with your out param name.

[]s